# Getting data from siblings to node where the data equals other node's data

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, merge, matching

I'm working with two XML documents in one XSLT document, and try to merge the data to be put into one HTML document.

The documents matches on one point, the id. The id is to be found as an attribute to the car node in *foo1.xml*. Regarding *foo2.xml* the id can be found inside the Data node, which is a child of the first Cell node (which is a child of the Row node). The Cell nodes that follows this first Cell node contains of Data nodes, which contains of the desired data (color and condition).

When in the XSLT document the data is added to the td cells, I (in some way) need to find the correct id in *foo2.xml*, and put in the car's color and condition in the last two td's.

In the XSLT document below you can see my failed try to do this. So, how can this be done?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Note: The order of the id's isn't the same in the two files.

**foo1.xml:**

```
<cars>
  <car id="8">
    <brand>Saab</brand>
    <model>95</model>
    <year>2011</year>
  </car>
  <car id="57">
    <brand>Chrysler</brand>
    <model>Voyager</model>
    <year>2010</year>
  </cars>
  ...
```

**foo2.xml:**

```
<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="5" ss:ExpandedRowCount="79" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultColumnWidth="65" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Column ss:Index="2" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="43"/>
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="113"/>
   <Column ss:Index="5" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="220"/>
   <Row ss:Index="6">
    <Cell ss:Index="3" ss:StyleID="s62"/>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:Index="3" ss:StyleID="s62"/>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:Index="3" ss:StyleID="s62"/>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:Index="2"><Data ss:Type="String">57</Data></Cell>    // <-- where the id is to be found
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">Yellow</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">New</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:Index="2"><Data ss:Type="Number">8</Data></Cell>    // <-- where the id is to be found
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="Number">Black</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">Used</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:Index="2"><Data ss:Type="Number">25</Data></Cell>    // <-- where the id is to be found
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="Number">Blue</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">Used</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   ...
```

**merge.xsl:**

```
   <- declarations... ->
         xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" >   <-- the XML namespace (ss:)

    <xsl:variable name="foo2" select="document('foo2.xml')" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Cars</title>
            </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="cars" />
        </body>  
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cars">

    <xsl:for-each select="$foo2//ss:Row">
        <xsl:value-of select="ss:Cell/ss:Data/text()" />
    </xsl:for-each>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th> <th>Brand</th> <th>Model</th> <th>Year</th> <th>Color</th> <th>Condition</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="car" />
    </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="car">
        <xsl:variable name="id" select="data[2]/text()" />
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@id" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="brand" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="model" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="year" /></td>

                <td><xsl:value-of select="$positions//ss:Row/ss:Cell/ss:Data=@id/preceding-sibling::ss:Cell" /></td> <-- failed try (color)
                <td> ??? (Condition) </td>
            </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kRowById" match="Row" use="Cell[1]/Data"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDoc2" select="document('file:///c:/temp/delete/foo2.xml')"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="car">
  <xsl:variable name="vId" select="@id"/>
  <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     <xsl:for-each select="$vDoc2">
       <color><xsl:value-of select="key('kRowById', $vId)/Cell[2]/Data"/></color>
       <condition><xsl:value-of select="key('kRowById', $vId)/Cell[3]/Data"/></condition>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided `foo1.xml` document**:

```
<cars>
    <car id="8">
        <brand>Saab</brand>
        <model>95</model>
        <year>2011</year>
    </car>
    <car id="57">
        <brand>Chrysler</brand>
        <model>Voyager</model>
        <year>2010</year>
    </car>
</cars>
```

**and having the provided `foo2.xml` document residing at: `c:\temp\delete`:**

```
    <Table xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
       xmlns:x="some:x"
       ss:ExpandedColumnCount="5" ss:ExpandedRowCount="79" x:FullColumns="1"
       x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultColumnWidth="65" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
       <Column ss:Index="2" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="43"/>
       <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="113"/>
       <Column ss:Index="5" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="220"/>
       <Row ss:Index="6">
        <Cell ss:Index="3" ss:StyleID="s62"/>
       </Row>
       <Row>
        <Cell ss:Index="3" ss:StyleID="s62"/>
       </Row>
       <Row>
        <Cell ss:Index="3" ss:StyleID="s62"/>
       </Row>
       <Row>
        <Cell ss:Index="2"><Data ss:Type="String">57</Data></Cell>    // -- where the id is to be found
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">Yellow</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">New</Data></Cell>
       </Row>
       <Row>
        <Cell ss:Index="2"><Data ss:Type="Number">8</Data></Cell>    // -- where the id is to be found
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="Number">Black</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">Used</Data></Cell>
       </Row>
       <Row>
        <Cell ss:Index="2"><Data ss:Type="Number">25</Data></Cell>    // -- where the id is to be found
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="Number">Blue</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">Used</Data></Cell>
       </Row>
</Table>
```

**produces the wanted and correct merge output**:

```
<cars>
   <car id="8">
      <brand>Saab</brand>
      <model>95</model>
      <year>2011</year>
      <color>Black</color>
      <condition>Used</condition>
   </car>
   <car id="57">
      <brand>Chrysler</brand>
      <model>Voyager</model>
      <year>2010</year>
      <color>Yellow</color>
      <condition>New</condition>
   </car>
</cars>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of:

1. The **[`document()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-document)** function.
2. **[Keys](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key)**.
3. The **[`<xsl:for-each>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#element-for-each)** instruction to change the current document. In XSLT 1.0 the **[`key()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-key)** function operates on the *current document*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I suppose this solution could be "converted" into a table as well, which is the output I want?

Comment: @holyredbeard, Yes, and any additional work is left as exercise to you :)